# Fetching information from SVN

Tags: svn, subclipse

*Background:*
SVN server installed in linux server. Using subclipse to check in files from Windows XP. I don't have admin access for SVN.
Every time I check in a file SVN will generate the revision number.

*Question:*
How to get the files checked between one revision number and another?

For example, I'd like to fetch all files from build 1 (I know the revision number) to the last checked in version from Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it should give you the difference between two revisions, put in your own params as needed.

svn diff -r ${startingSvnRevision}:${endingSvnRevision} --summarize ${RepoURL}

Comment: Whats is this 'svn'? i am using windows xp and thru subecplise i am checking in the files. Do i need to install any additional software?

Comment: @Madhu, subclipse is not a fully featured svn client. It won't allow you to do many of these types of tasks. You'd be better off learning svn command line or using something like tortoisesvn.

Comment: yes that's command line svn command.  Most likely you do have a svn command line client installed already that subcplise uses on your xp machine.

Comment: @jasonbar I disagree with the assertion that Subclipse is not a full fledged svn client.  This is a pretty obscure request and it is not necessarily obvious how it fits in with a GUI, let alone an IDE integration.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know what the question is, so there could be a lot of ways to answer it.

In the SVN Repository Browsing view, right-click on the path and choose Compare.  Then enter the two Revisions you want and you will see a summarized list of the changes.  You can then double-click on any file to see a graphical compare of the differences.

The Show History option will show all the changes on a selected path, which might also be what you want.

Finally, you might also want something like Team > Synchronize with Repository which will show all the incoming changes from the repository to your working copy and let you see differences etc.